# UNO game card functionalities

Tags: c++

I am having trouble building the last piece to my game, the card's functionality. If you aren't familiar with the rules of UNO, https://www.unorules.com/

My issue is that I am not sure how to build my "Reverse" and "Skip" functions. I have a vector of "player" objects that control whos turn it is, by iteration.

In my head, it seems pretty straight forward. Skip will just increment the index by one, skipping the previous player object, and Reverse will decrement the index instead of incrementing, therefore, going backward.

I just can't seem to apply this idea into code.

This is my first big project and I feel a little overwhelmed with all the code.

I've built a skip function but haven't actually put anything in it because I don't know where to start. I feel like the way I am iterating through each turn is inefficient and messy, so I may need help refactoring it.

edit:
here si what i think is acceptable Reverse code

```
void Game::round(Player& player, Deck& deck)
{
    // 1 round has x turns

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        if (reverse = true) //reverse is not defined in below code
        {
            for (int i; i < amountOfPlayers; i--)
            {
                if (i < 0)
                {
                    i = playerVector.size()-1;
                }
                turns(player, deck, i);
            }
        }

        turns(player, deck, i);
    }
}
```

**This is my game code**

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
#include "DevTest.h"

class Player;
class DevTest;
class Deck;
class Global;
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Game
{
private:
    int amountOfPlayers;
    std::vector<Player*> playerVector;
    std::vector<Card> inPlay; //cards in play

public:
    Game();
    void createPlayerVector(Deck& deck);
    void menu(Deck &deck, Player &player, Game game, DevTest devtest);
    void round(Player& player, Deck& deck);
    void turns(Player &player, Deck &deck, int i);
    bool win(Player& player);
    void playGame(Player& player, Game game, Deck& deck);
    bool chooseCard(Player& player, Deck deck, int position);

    void drawTwo(Deck &deck, int drawAmount, int playerIndex);
    void drawWild(Deck& deck, int cardNum, int playerIndex, int toChoose);
    void skip(Player player, Deck& deck, int i);
    ~Game();
};



/*

#include "Game.h"
class DevTest;

Game::Game()
{
    Deck deck;
}

void Game::createPlayerVector(Deck &deck)
{

    std::string userName;
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of players: ";
    std::cin >> amountOfPlayers;

    if (amountOfPlayers < 2 || amountOfPlayers>10)
    {
        if (amountOfPlayers < 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry! Not enough players." << std::endl;
        }

        if (amountOfPlayers > 10)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry! Too many players." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the names of each player." << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            Player* player = new Player;
            playerVector.push_back(player);

            std::cout << "Player " << i+1 << ": ";

            std::cin.ignore();

            std::getline(std::cin, userName);

            this->playerVector[i]->setUserName(userName);
            this->playerVector[i]->setHand(deck, *player);
            player->printHand(deck);
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
return;
}

void Game::menu(Deck& deck, Player& player, Game game, DevTest devtest)
{
    int choice;

    std::cout << "UNO" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Play Game" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Read Rules" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Developer Testing" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. Quit" << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Play Game" << std::endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            std::cout << "Read Rules" << std::endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            std::cout << "Developer Testing" << std::endl;
            devtest.testMenu(deck, player, game);
            break;

        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose again." << std::endl;
        }
        //clear screen
    } while (choice < 1 || choice >4);
}

void Game::round(Player& player, Deck& deck)
{
    // 1 round has x turns

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        turns(player, deck, i);
    }
}

void Game::turns(Player& player, Deck& deck, int playerIndex)
{   
    int option;
    bool proceed = false;

    do
    {

        std::cout << "It is currently " << playerVector[playerIndex]->getUserName() << "'s" << " turn." << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The card you must match is: " << std::endl;

        deck.toString(inPlay.front().color);
        std::cout << " " << inPlay.front().value << std::endl << std::endl;

        std::cout << "[1] Draw Card " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[2] Play Card" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Pick an option. " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> option;

        if (option == 1)
        {
            //draw card
            deck.dealCard(*playerVector[playerIndex]);
            std::cout << "You have taken a card." << std::endl;
        }

        if (option == 2)
        {
            //use card, transfer hand to bottom of deck
            proceed = chooseCard(player, deck, playerIndex);
        }

        if (win(player) == true)
        {
            //end game, celebrate
            return;
        }

        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");

    } while (proceed == false);
}

bool Game::win(Player& player)
{

    if (player.isEmpty(player) == true)
    {
        //you win
        //std::cout << "Congratulations, " << player.getUserName() << " you win!" << std::endl;
        //return true;
    }

    else
    {
        //nobody has won yet
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

void Game::playGame(Player& player, Game game, Deck& deck)
{
//cout intro();
    deck.createDeck();
    deck.shuffle();

    createPlayerVector(deck);

    //start off game by placing a single card down
    inPlay.push_back(deck.getCard());
    deck.pop();

    //remove choose card from hand
    //pop off deck to start game (starting card)
    while (win(player) == false)
    {
        round(player, deck);
    }

}

bool Game::chooseCard(Player& player, Deck deck, int playerIndex) //delete from hand, populate inPlay
{
    int toChoose;
    bool validate = false;
    std::cout << "Which card would you like to choose? Press 0 to draw a card." << std::endl;

    while (validate == false)
    {
        this->playerVector[playerIndex]->printHand(deck);
        std::cin >> toChoose;

        if (toChoose == 0)
        {
            //fix
            deck.dealCard(*playerVector[playerIndex]); //fix
            return false;
        }

        if (playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 13 || playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 14)
        {
            validate = true;
            int cardNum = playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value;
            drawWild(deck, cardNum, playerIndex, toChoose);
        }




        else if (playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value != inPlay.front().value && playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).color != inPlay.front().color)
        {
            //card doesn't match
            validate = false;
            std::cout << "You are not allowed to play this card!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        validate = true;
    }



    if (validate == true)
    {
        if (playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 10 || playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 14)

        {
            int drawAmount = 0;

            //draw two
            if (playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 10)
            {
                int drawAmount = 2;
                drawTwo(deck, drawAmount, playerIndex + 1);
            }
        }

        if(playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 11 || playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose).value == 12)
        {
            skip(player, deck, playerIndex);
        }

        inPlay.insert(inPlay.begin(), playerVector[playerIndex]->getHandCard(player, toChoose));
        playerVector[playerIndex]->deleteHand(toChoose);
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}


void Game::drawTwo(Deck &deck, int drawAmount, int playerIndex)
{
    if (playerIndex>playerVector.size()-1)
    {
        playerIndex = 0; //circular code
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < drawAmount; j++)
    {
        deck.dealCard(*playerVector[playerIndex]);
    }
}

void Game::drawWild(Deck& deck, int cardNum, int playerIndex, int toChoose) //fix
{
    if (cardNum == 13)
    {
        int choice;
        //wild
        std::cout << "What color would you like to choose?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[1] BLUE" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[2] GREEN" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[3] RED" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[4] YELLOW" << std::endl;


        std::cin >> choice;


        //inPlay.front().color = static_cast<Card::Color>(choice - 1);
        //
    }

    if (cardNum == 14)
    {
        //draw 4
        //lets u pick a color AND next person draws 4
    }
}

void Game::skip(Player player, Deck& deck, int i)
{
    //turns(player, deck, i + 1);
}


Game::~Game()
{

}
```

**A player is defined as**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Card.h"

class Deck;
class Player
{
private:
    int length;
    std::string username; //can indicate whos turn / wins
    static const int HANDSIZE = 7;
    std::vector<Card> hand;

public:
    Player();
    void pushHand(Card deck); 
    void deleteHand(int position);
    void printHand(Deck deck);
    void setHand(Deck &deck, Player& player); 
    Card getHandCard(Player& player, int position);
    int getHANDSIZE();
    std::string getUserName();
    void setUserName(std::string name);
    bool isEmpty(Player& player); //hand is empty

    ~Player();
};


#include "Player.h"
class Player;

Player::Player()
{
    this->length = 0;
}

void Player::pushHand(Card deck)
{
    //push 1 deck object into hand

    this->hand.push_back(deck);
    length++;
}

void Player::deleteHand(int position)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == position-1)
        {
            hand.erase(hand.begin()+i);
        }
    }
}

void Player::printHand(Deck deck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i+1 << ". ";
        std::cout << "Color: ";
        deck.toString(hand[i].color);
        std::cout << " | " << "Value: " << hand[i].value << std::endl;
    }
}

void Player::setHand(Deck &deck, Player& player) //used only for setting hand at beginning of game
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HANDSIZE; i++)
    {
        deck.dealCard(player);
    }
}

Card Player::getHandCard(Player& player, int position)
{
    return this->hand[position - 1];
    //return player.hand[position - 1];
}

int Player::getHANDSIZE()
{
    return HANDSIZE;
}

std::string Player::getUserName()
{
    return username;
}

void Player::setUserName(std::string name)
{
    username = name;
}

bool Player::isEmpty(Player& player)
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


Player::~Player()
{
    //delete hand;
}
```

**Deck is**

```
  #pragma once
    #include "Card.h"
    #include "Player.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>

    class Player;
    class Deck 
    {
    private:

        static const int MAXSIZE = 108; //108 cards in UNO
        int length;

    public:
        Deck();

        void createDeck();
        void shuffle();
        void printDeck();
        //void push();
        void pop();
        int top();

        bool isEmpty();
        bool isFull();
        void toString(Card::Color color); //converts enum to string.
        void dealCard(Player &player);
        Card getCard();
        Card* deck;

        ~Deck();
    };


#include "Deck.h"



Deck::Deck()
{
    deck = new Card[MAXSIZE];
    length = 0;
}

void Deck::createDeck()
{
    //UNO has 4 zero cards
    int num = 0;

    for (int col = 0; col <= 3; col++)
    {
        deck[length].value = num; //sets each to zero
        deck[length].color = static_cast<Card::Color>(col); //sets each card to a color, iterates through enum
        length++;
    }

    //card value 1-9 , draw-two (10), skip (11), reverse (12)
    for (num = 1; num <= 12; num++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= 3; col++)
            {
                deck[length].value = num;
                deck[length].color = static_cast<Card::Color>(col);
                length++;
            }
        }
    }

    //wild(13) and draw four(14)
    for (num = 13; num <= 14; num++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            deck[length].value = num;
            deck[length].color = Card::Color::WILD;
            length++;
        }
    }

}


void Deck::shuffle() //fisher-yates algorithm
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j = (rand() % (i + 1));
        std::swap(deck[j], deck[i]);
    }

}

void Deck::printDeck()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Length: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value: " << deck[i].value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Color: ";
        toString(deck[i].color);
    }
}

void Deck::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty() == false)
    {
        length--;
    }
}

int Deck::top()
{
    if (isEmpty() == false)
    {
        return length - 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool Deck::isEmpty()
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Deck::isFull()
{
    if (length >= MAXSIZE)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


void Deck::toString(Card::Color color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case Card::Color::BLUE:
        std::cout << "Blue";
        break;

    case Card::Color::GREEN:
        std::cout << "Green";
        break;

    case Card::Color::RED:
        std::cout << "Red";
        break;

    case Card::Color::YELLOW:
        std::cout << "Yellow";
        break;

    case Card::Color::WILD:
        std::cout << "Wild";
        break;
    }
    return;
}


void Deck::dealCard(Player &player) 
{
    player.pushHand(deck[top()]);
    pop();
    return;
}

Card Deck::getCard()
{
    return deck[length-1];
}


Deck::~Deck()
{
}
```

**where each Card in Deck is**

```
#pragma once

class Card
{
private:


public:
    enum Color { BLUE, GREEN, RED, YELLOW, WILD };
    Card();
    Color color;
    int value;
    Card(Color color, int value);

    ~Card();
};


   #include "Card.h"

Card::Card()
{
}

Card::Card(Color color, int value)
{
    color = this->color;
    value = this->value;
}

Card::~Card()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can just put iteration int into member m_currentIterator of Game and iteration direction as bool m_isReversed (true = normal, false = reversed).

When player will use 'Reverse' card you just change m_isReversed to !m_isReversed; and iterate in reversed if(m_isReversed) i-- else i++.

When player will use 'Skip' you just use m_currentIterator++;

I know that it's not the best way and its ugly code (using stupid members), but it will work pretty good :)

Comment: Wouldn't that only work for one reverse card though? What if a reverse card is placed after a consecutive reverse card? How will it basically reverse the reverse card?

Comment: @TylerLe It will work. You just store direction of iteration in a member of Game class in bool type. So if you have m_isReversed==false you increment your iterator and when you have m_isReversed==true you decrement your iterator. When player use 'Reverse' card you just change m_isReversed to its own negation :)

Comment: @TylerLe Example: You have m_isReversed = false, so the iterator is incrementing, one of players use 'Revese' and the m_isReversed = !m_isReversed(what means false in this example) . Now you have iterator decrementing. When player will use next 'Reverse' you will again change m_isReversed = !m_isReversed (what means true now) and iterator will be incremented.  You just need to change your round method